# Excel. Finding a specific casenumber in projectext and connecting employee name to it

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Image of the problem, can't post images directly yet]

Hi people, my question seems really simple, but I cannot find an answer, even after searching. I need to find the casenumber in the projectext and connect the employee name to it. I'll refer to the image numbers.

Nr. 1. Is the project text. 
Example: D20160084 Piet K.A. - D1606076 - Bezwaar ingangsdatum uitkering - BIP 30 sep 2016 - 4ME6093

Nr. 2. Are the employees with their employee IDnumbers 01 to 07.

Nr. 3. I need to find a code to extract the casenumber, as seen in the first row. The casenumber D1606076 consists of three parts.

- D16 = year 2016
- 06 = employeenumber
- 076 = number of the case

Nr. 4. I also need to find a code to extract the employee connected to the casenumber, as seen in the first row.

Anyone that can help?:)

- I'm not sure if I can link to the workbook. Please let me know if it is not permitted. Link to workbook:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/17uv8ft9fyorlau/Searching%20for%20casenumber%20and%20employee%20number.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you require vba for this but the following can easily be translated from worksheet functions to vba code.

The case number can be retrieved with,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E10, "-", REPT(" ", LEN(E10))), LEN(E10), LEN(E10)))
```

The employee can be retrieved with,

```
=INDEX(G$1:G$7, MATCH(MID(E3, 4, 2)&".", F$1:F$7, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jeeped! It works like a charm! Results from applying it to the big sheet:

Problem 1:
- Problem with the formula is if the casenumber contains a "–" (large) instead of a "-" (small), then the code breaks. 
- For example:
Project: D20160166 John d. – D1706043 – Tekst tekst tekst - BIP 19-04-2017 - 3ML9999
Brings back: BIP 19
- For now I will just use replace "–" for "-". (It made 25 adjusments, in a sheet of 597 lines.

Comment: Problem 2:
- Another problem is when somebody is called papa-oete, then it takes the name oete. I'll just have to be weary of these kinds of cases
- For example:
Project: D20160076 Papa-Oete - D1606068 - Tekst tekst tekst - John 16 sep 2016 - 12MD3444
Brings back: Oete

- For the rest the code seems solid! 

- For now I'll just have to manually check the columns of casenumbers(D1606076)/employees(Harvey) through the filter for errors like #Value/#NA or weird names instead of casenumbers.

Answer (score 1):

For the casenumber you could use in I10:

```
=MID(E10,FIND('-',E10)+2,8)
```

and for the employee in J10:

```
=INDEX($G$1:$G$7,MATCH(MID(I10,4,2)&'.',$F$1:$F$7,0))
```

drag down as needed.

Comment: Thank you Marco Getrost It works like a charm! Results from applying it to the big sheet: Problem 1: - Problem with the formula is if the casenumber contains a "–" (large) instead of a "-" (small), then the code breaks. - For example: Project: D20160166 John d. – D1706043 – Tekst tekst tekst - BIP 19-04-2017 - 3ML9999 Brings back: BIP 19 - For now I will just use replace "–" for "-". (It made 25 adjusments, in a sheet of 597 lines.

Comment: Problem 2: - Another problem is when somebody is called papa-oete, then it takes the name oete. I'll just have to be weary of these kinds of cases - For example: Project: D20160076 Papa-Oete - D1606068 - Tekst tekst tekst - John 16 sep 2016 - 12MD3444 Brings back: Oete - For the rest the code seems solid! - For now I'll just have to manually check the columns of casenumbers(D1606076)/employees(Harvey) through the filter for errors like #Value/#NA or weird names instead of casenumbers. Thank you as well for your help!:)

Comment: Seems I can only gift one person the best answer :(. Both of you seem to be right tho!

Comment: @San I see your point. But I don't think you will be able to find a formula where you can cover all cases. If VBA would be an option, then this could be done easily.

Comment: '@Marco really? How would you do it with VBA?